MacBook Pro 16 M3 2023: What happens if both MagSafe and USB PD (via Thuderbolt Dock) and plugged in?
What happens if, on a MacBook Pro 16" M3 2023, both MagSafe and a Thunderbolt Dock, such as the CalDigit TS4 Thunderbolt 4 Dock, which delivers 98W (might not enough if the MacBook is used heavily as the MagSafe Pmax=140W) are plugged in? Will one of the two power inputs be ignored? Is this safe?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but yes, it will use the power source that can provide the most power.
This question contains a quote from a now-defunct Apple Support page:


Your MacBook Pro draws power from only one power supply, even if more than one is attached—so using multiple power supplies won't speed
up charging.

If you connect multiple power supplies to your MacBook Pro, the one that provides the most power will be used, regardless of the order in
which you connected them.




Not a clear answer as MagSafe is not mentioned. I can only infer that MagSafe will take priority over USB-C PD because 140W (MagSafe) > 100W, which is what most USB-C PD are able to output so far. There should be a clear-cut answer on this as I've seen motherboards die with powered USB hubs and such.
